# Use require only once

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file including many files by the use of require. Some of them are helper files. While other are functions of nodes. I want those helper functions to be included anywhere.

```
module.exports = {
    node1: require('node1.js'),
    functions1: require('./functionsq.js'),
}
```

However, this way i cannot use function1 in node1. Is there a way to use functions1 in node1, while it must not be included in the node file again by require?

```
**var f=require('functions.js')**
var node1={
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `module.exports = {
    node1: module.exports && module.exports.node1 ? module.exports.node1:  require('node1.js'),
}`?